# Craft localisation caching error

Tags: cache, craft2

long time listener, first time caller.

I'm having some issues getting localisation setup on my homestead/vagrant craft 2 site. I'm running into issues, I believe, with the craft cache when I try to visit a localised url I have set up.

I've been following the guide [here](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/localization-guide.html), but haven't been able to have any luck with it.

I am using the folder structure in my public folder as follows

```
    /public  
      -index.php  
      -.htaccess  
      /es
        -index.php  
        -.htaccess
```

My config/general.php file is like this,

```
    define('URI_SCHEME', (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) ? "https://" : 
    "http://");
    define('SITE_URL',    URI_SCHEME.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
    define('BASEPATH',     realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../'));

    return array(


    '*' => array(
      'appId' => 'app',
      'validationKey' => getenv('VALIDATION_KEY'),
      'devMode' => true,
      'backupDbOnUpdate' => false,
      'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,

      'siteUrl' => array(
         'en' => 'http://example.test/',
         'es' => 'http://example.test/es/'
      ),
      'cacheMethod' => getenv('CACHE_METHOD'),

      'environmentVariables' => array(
        'basePath' => BASEPATH,
        'siteUrl'  => SITE_URL

      ),
     ),

    ),
    )
```

My public/es/index.php file is pointing to the correct craft folder and has a `define(CRAFT_LOCALE, 'es')`. I'm stuck as how to progress and any pointers or tips are very appreciated
Heres a screen shot of the actual error on example.test/es
[image]

Comment: Is there anything else in your `config/general.php` file?  If so, can you edit the question to share the whole thing?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is this is the cause:

```
'cacheMethod' => getenv('CACHE_METHOD'),
```

`getenv('CACHE_METHOD')` is probably returning `null` because that environment variable isn't being set like you expect or its set to an unknown caching driver.